# How do I mount a flat object on a rounded roof tile?

Tags: mounting, construction

My objective is to mount the plastic (Home Depot) owl in the 1st image below (flat underneath) at the end of the roof in the 2nd image. Although you can't see the roof in the image where it will mount it has a rounded tile.

What would be the best/easiest way to do this? Or asked more generically, how does a flat bottomed object get mounted securely onto a rounded surface?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My pidgeon friends assure me your tawdry trick will fool noone. They laugh at your owl.

That said, you can attach the owl by creating using wax to make a dam, attach some wax to the decoy to temporarily hold it inside the dam, then pour a strong epoxy into the dam around it. If done correctly, a big block of epoxy will harden onto the roof, permanently attaching the owl.

Mortar can be used as an alternative to epoxy.